# Does anyone know of a good Graphic Design contract I can find online to give clients?

Tags: adobe-indesign, client-relations, contract

Does anyone know of a good Graphic Design contract I can find online to give clients? - I came across this site because a client keeps asking for the InDesign source files and I don't have a proper contract written up with her. In future I'd like to cover myself so I don't continually get burned!

Any links to where I can find a good contract for designers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/what-should-be-in-a-job-contract

Answer (score 1):

The AIGA has a good sample contract you can start with: http://www.aiga.org/standard-agreement/ It's *very* detailed, and you will likely need to tweak it for your own jobs.

See this question for ideas about how you can modify it for yourself:

[What should be in a job contract?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5787/what-should-be-in-a-job-contract)

Comment: @SilverSquare Thanks! If you like my answer, please upvote it by clicking on the top diamond, and then if you like you can click on the checkmark to select this as the accepted answer. This is how the SE community works. :)